# How to print background images and colors in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, microsoft-edge

Although the browsers like IE and FF offer an option for the user to set when including backgrounds in prints, Edge doesn't seem to have this option in it's printer setup.

Is there a way one can activate this through code or native Edge JS command?

Comment: I'd guess it hasn't been implemented yet - even normal image printing is haphazardous in Edge at the moment. I don't think there would be a way to override it, as the print function in all major browsers cannot run the js on the page.

Comment: I've been running a Windows 10 VM for a while, and EDGE worked fine once IE 11's print settings had background colors selected. However, I recently upgraded to the latest Windows 10, and now EDGE won't print background colors. Looks like something was broken, and I can't find any place to configure it.

Comment: for a background image workaround , maybe try putting it in a after tag, e.g, `div::after {
  content: url(image.jpg);
}`

Comment: Please vote for "Allow Edge to print background colors" on [User Voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/18681946-allow-edge-to-print-background-colors)

Answer (score 1):

This is Q&A - but I'm NOT going to accept it as the answer. So, please write yours too.

There is no apparent solution for this with Edge browser as of April 2017. Edge simply doesn't include background shades in its prints. This is lack of feature and is evident when you go to [outlook.com](http://outlook.com) (from Microsoft itself) to print your calendar with background colors via Edge.

One, though awkward, solution the Edge offers is the "Open with IE" menu item. This works - but works only for static pages as it tries to open the current URL right in IE.

---

The workaround I did for my application was to include a "Save for IE" button on my print page. When clicked, it goes through the current DOM tree of the printable page, creates a string of markup (with adjustments if necessary) and then offers the user to save it as a single file.

Now the user can open this with IE to send straight into printing.

---

Not good enough! But better than making your application look incapable with Edge. IF all these are not working, just create an `svg` element on top of where you want to print the background and give the `svg` element a fill color.

---

Edit:

Converting all my backgrounds to foreground by replacing divs with labels did the trick. It went better than I expected with transforming etc.

Comment: What do you mean by converting to foreground?

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I replaced a div with a label element but it didn't make the backgroud-color show up in the print.  Are you using background, or background-color, or some other approach to get things showing up in the print?

Comment: @Charlie I can get my solid color working by using a canvas with a fill color of my choice.  How are you doing it with label?